Uber driver cancels trip because they don't have a baby car seat
I just booked a ride with Uber and the driver which showed up asked me to cancel because I was with a 2yo baby and they didn't have a baby seat in the car. I didn't request a baby seat, AFAIK, Uber doesn't offer such option.
I initially accepted a cancellation fee of 7 euro, but I see I can still request a refund via support. Should I? Is it my fault that I didn't find a way to request the baby seat (and didn't bring my own)? I don't want to punish the driver for something they weren't responsible for.

For what it's worth, official taxis are exempt from the car seat requirement under French law.  So you might consider using them to get around instead if you don't have a car seat.  Ubers do not fall under this exemption, since they're not officially "taxis".

In UK the seat belt exemption also applies to minicabs – private hire (where uber sails close to the wind). Otherwise they would need to carry about 9 child seats in the car, which is clearly impractical. Perhaps there was another reason (a journey they didn't want?) and the driver used that as an excuse.

I believe that you should never cancel a trip if a driver asks you to do so. If there is your fault, the driver should cancel a trip themselves, and contact the drivers' support to avoid any fines etc. If the driver asks you to cancel, this means that they have no legitimate reason to cancel, but just do not want to take the journey and want to avoid any penalties for cancelling.

@Petr Wouldn't walking away from the car without cancelling open me to a no-show fee?

@DmitryGrigoryev I don't use Uber, but for a generic taxi app service I would contact the support to say that the driver refuses to go and asks to cancel the trip (and hope that this will be enough to avoid a no-show fee), after which I'll just order another car (if the app allows it).

Did you communicate to the driver while you were making your booking that one of the passengers is a 2yo baby? How is the Uber driver supposed to know that you have a baby but no baby seat? Or do you assume that every Uber driver has one of each size of infant/baby/toddler/booster seat?

French law(fr) states that

(...) lorsqu'un siège n'est pas équipé de ceinture de sécurité, il est interdit d'y transporter un enfant de moins de trois ans


De même, le conducteur doit s'assurer que tout enfant de moins de dix ans est retenu par un système homologué de retenue pour enfant adapté à sa morphologie et à son poids.

This translates to

(...) when a seat is not equipped with a seat belt, it is prohibited to transport a child under three years of age


Similarly, the driver must ensure that any child under ten years of age is restrained by an approved child restraint system adapted to their morphology and weight.

Another governmental site(fr) gives more details, highlighting the baby seat requirements.
They have seat belts, but must also have a baby seat. Surprisingly enough, I did not find any mention about that on the French site, but there is one on the French-Canadian one. It is explicitly mentioned that if you do not have a seat, you can cancel the trip.
As per the comments - I would have asked the driver to cancel the trip and explain that they could not take you in because of the baby.
